# libz.tbd, missing required architecture unknown

Tags: ios, xcode, libz

My project uses `libz.tdb` in the build phases.

On the simulator, all is well. But when I try to run it on my iPhone 6, I get:

```
ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd, missing required architecture unknown in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (3 slices)
```

Why is it looking for an "unknown" architecture?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe its Architectures debug and release error.
>   First of all go to your projects Build Settings.
>   then go to Architectures in Build Settings.there is debug and release option in these option you want to select Standard architectures(armv7,armv64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD).
>   In your plist file add Required device capabilities as string armv7. 
>   May its working.